# Is is possible to use OpenCV.js with Web Worker in Angular?

Tags: angular, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV.js in web workers in Angular. My project needs to conduct multiple graphic computings at the same time, which would take long time.

But when I use OpenCV in a *.worker.ts file like components, it said function not defined.

blur.worker.ts:

```js
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  const src = data.src;
  const color = data.color;
  const kSize = data.kSize;
  if (color === false) {
    cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0);
  }
  const dst = new cv.Mat();
  if (kSize > 0) {
    cv.medianBlur(src, dst, kSize);
  } else {
    src.copyTo(dst);
  }
  postMessage({dst});
});
```

Main thread (a service):

```js
const src = cv.imread(srcImg.nativeElement.id);
const worker = new Worker('../workers/blur.worker.ts', { type: 'module' });
worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
  cv.imshow(dstImg.nativeElement.id, data.dst);
};
worker.postMessage({src, color, args});
```

It seems opencv.js has been loaded, but web worker cannot access it.

Answer (score 2):

This took me a stupidly long time to figure out.
But here you go everyone.

```js
addEventListener('message', async (data) => {
  self["Module"] = {
    scriptUrl: '/assets/opencv/opencv.js',
    wasmBinaryFile: '/assets/opencv/opencv_js.wasm',
    usingWasm: true,
    onRuntimeInitialized: () => { }
  }

  //Hack to fake correct path to .wasm file
  let scriptDirectory = self.location.href
  scriptDirectory = scriptDirectory.substr(0, scriptDirectory.lastIndexOf("/")) + self["Module"].wasmBinaryFile;
  let document = { currentScript: { src: scriptDirectory } }
  self["document"] = document;

  //Load and await the .js OpenCV
  self.importScripts(self["Module"].scriptUrl);
  cv = await cv;

  //!!Use cv here!!

  postMessage(response);
});
```

Normaly when loading OpenCV, the Module infomation is declared globlay using `window["Module"]`, however as we are a web worker, we don't have acess to window. Instead i replaced this with `self["Module"]`.

The hack using `scriptDirectory` is designed to take advantage of the `_scriptDir` variable (in opencv.js) to overide the nasty `scriptDirectory` generated in the `ENVIROMENT_IS_WORKER` if else block.

Have fun!

for Typescript
replace

```js
self["document"] = document;
self.importScripts(self["Module"].scriptUrl);
```

with

```js
//@ts-ignore
self["document"] = document;
//@ts-ignore
self.importScripts(self["Module"].scriptUrl);
```

(Do bear in mind that this will load opencv from the server every time the worker is pinnged, consider moving this code outside of the onmessage)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix by removing this code block from generated opencv.js file, present at the top of the file. 'cv' object will be returned as promise.

```
else if (typeof importScripts === 'function') {
      // Web worker
      root.cv = factory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For guys looking for importing OpenCV in module workers, i.e.

```
new Worker('worker.js', { type: 'module' })
```

I've come up with the following solution.

1. Download "opencv-4.5.5.js" from OpenCV official site
   https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/d84/tutorial_js_usage.html
2. Change this file (1):
   Add `let Module;` to the first line, so that line 44-46 will not give you error.

```
  // line 44-46
  if (typeof Module === 'undefined')
    Module = {};
  return cv(Module);
```

3. Change this file (2):
   As you will find `root` be undefined, and it comes from line 22.
   Make a fallback to `self` which we use for workers.

```
  } else {
    // Other shells, e.g. d8
    root.cv = factory();
  }
}(this||self, function () {   // <-- original: }(this, function () {
  
var cv = (function() {
```

4. Change this file (3):
   Find this and give it a missing ()

```
  } else if (typeof importScripts === 'function') {
    // Web worker
    root.cv = factory();   // original: root.cv = factory;
  }
```

5. I created a wrapper for the import, `opencv-wrapper.js`

```
await import("/lib/opencv-4.5.5.js");  // where your modified file locate
export default cv;
```

6. Import as normal

```
import cv from "/lib/opencv-wrapper.js"; // where you place your wrapper
```